# How to reduce ping?

Tags: ping, latency

I've created a browser game.
I use

- Server-side - Node.js
- Client - html, js
- Cloudflare
- Servers located - US, Europe

When I play the game using a European server, my ping is about 40. But sometimes it raises up to 700/1000. How can I solve it? Should I change hosting? (currently - I use the digital  ocean droplets for 5$)

- The game is http://sigmally.com/
- [Game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj3Iy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to identify what the issue is.

Check that your internet connection is not the problem. Use an alternative internet connection avoid VPNs for this check as they can slow your connection down.

Make sure you have adequate system resources to deal with the number of server requests.

For example Apache server will handle up to around 10000 clients at any one time.

Make sure you do not have an excessive amount of server requests.

Make sure that you have adequate processing power for the server. Check what percentage processing power you are using when you get long ping times.

Make sure that you have adequate RAM for the server. Check what percentage RAM you are using when you get long ping times.

Mare sure that the files you are requesting from the server are not located in a directory with thousands of other files as it will take the server longer to locate the file and serve it back to you.